# Mobifirst 8.0: Adapter cannot get data after upgrade MFP 7.1 to 8.0

Tags: java, android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

I have a profile adapter using https://randomuser.me/ API

adapter.xml

```
<wl:adapter name="comradeAdapter"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:wl="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration"
    xmlns:http="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration/http">

    <displayName>comradeAdapter</displayName>
    <description>comradeAdapter</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>https</protocol>
            <domain>api.randomuser.me</domain>
            <port>443</port>
            <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>50</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>
            <!-- Following properties used by adapter's key manager for choosing specific certificate from key store
            <sslCertificateAlias></sslCertificateAlias>
            <sslCertificatePassword></sslCertificatePassword>
            -->
        </connectionPolicy>
    </connectivity>

    <procedure name="getFeed"/>
</wl:adapter>
```

comradeAdapter.js

```
function getFeed() {
    path = '?results=20';

    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : path
    };


    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

On my local, I can invoke data successfully. But when I deploy to mobilefirst console server 8.0 which is provided by ibm bluemix, I cannot get data on Swagger:

Request URL

```
https://mydemo-tac-ha-server.mybluemix.net/mfp/api/adapters/comradeAdapter/getFeed

Response Body

no content

Response Code

401

Response Headers

{
  "x-backside-transport": "FAIL FAIL",
  "connection": "Keep-Alive",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "date": "Mon, 12 Sep 2016 10:15:57 GMT",
  "www-authenticate": "Bearer",
  "x-powered-by": "Servlet/3.1",
  "x-global-transaction-id": "3044026435",
  "content-type": null
}
```

Please hele me review and give me your thoughts to can get data from server mfp 8.0

Comment: what are you generally trying to achieve? This looks like leveraging comrade app lab resource with 8.0, but those were never upgraded for v8. You need to upgrade/re-create adapter cause WL.* APIs were replaces with MFP* and adapter structure was changed..

Comment: @AndriiVasylchenko: ohm, thanks for your sharing. I research it on internet and use mfpdev to create new adapter, but i don't know why some tutorials using mockServer instead the API. Do we have any tutorials guide_line to setup or migrated mfp 7.1 to 8.0 ? thanks.

Comment: @Pham you can follow upgrade labs from AdvancedWallet https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/labs/developers/8.0/advancedwallet/ or just follow the migration cookbook https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/migration-cookbook/

Comment: Getting a 401 response when using the Swagger UI is most likely due to a security issue. By default all MFP adapter procedures are protected therefore the Swagger UI will have to obtain a valid token before being able to call them. You can either make the procedure unsecured (not the best solution), or just tell Swagger UI to obtain a token before you actually make the call. You can do that by clicking on the "OFF" button on the top right of the resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To migrate existing adapters and applications to MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 there are the following materials:

- Cookbook: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/migration-cookbook/
- Example application migration: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/labs/developers/8.0/advancedwallet/